# Parameterized query with pyodbc and mysql8 returns 0 for columns with int data types

Tags: python, mysql, pyodbc

- Python: 2.7.12
- pyodbc: 4.0.24
- OS:  Ubuntu 16.4
- DB: MySQL 8
- driver: MySQL 8

Expected behaviour: resultset should have numbers in columns with datatype int

Actual Behaviour: All of the columns with int data type have 0's **(If parameterised query is used)**

Here's the queries -

  1.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE where id =7")
```

Result set:

```
[(7, 1, None, 1, u'An', u'Zed', None, u'Ms', datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 20, 0, 0), u'F', u'Not To Be Disclosed', None, None, u'SPRING', None, u'4000', datetime.datetime(2009, 5, 20, 18, 55), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 4, 14, 25, 58, 763000), 0, None, None, None, bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01(n\xba'))]
```

  2.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM patients where patient_id=?", [7])`
```

or

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM patients where patient_id=?", ['7'])
```

or

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM patients where patient_id IN ", [7])
```

Result set:

```
[(0, 0, None, 0, u'An', u'Zed', None, u'Ms', datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 20, 0, 0), u'F', u'Not To Be Disclosed', None, None, u'SPRING', None, u'4000', datetime.datetime(2009, 5, 20, 18, 55), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 4, 14, 25, 58, 763000), 0, None, None, None, bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01(n\xba'))]
```

Rest of the result set is okay except for the columns with int data type that all have 0's if paramterized query is used.

It seems like it should have worked without issues. Can I get some help here.

Edit : Here's the schema of the table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `patient
  `lastname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `known_as` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dob` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sex` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address3` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postcode` char(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datecreated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `dateupdated` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isrep` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo` longblob,
  `foreign_images_imported` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ismerged` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rowversion` varbinary(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`patient_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: @snakecharmerb Please let me know if you need any further information

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58459844/2144390

Comment: But this seems fairly basic use case to me . How are people getting around to it?

Comment: I suspect that most people working with MySQL from Python are using [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) instead of pyodbc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have encountered [this bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97191) in MySQL Connector/ODBC.

EDIT: The bug [has now been fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59724117/2144390).

---

The following (Python 3) test code verifies that MySQL Connector/ODBC returns zero (incorrect), while [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) returns the correct value:

```python
import MySQLdb  # from mysqlclient
import pyodbc

host = 'localhost'
user = 'root'
passwd = 'whatever'
db = 'mydb'
port = 3307
charset = 'utf8mb4'

use_odbc = False  # or True
print(f'{"" if use_odbc else "not "}using ODBC ...')

if use_odbc:
    connection_string = (
        f'DRIVER=MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver;'
        f'SERVER={host};UID={user};PWD={passwd};DATABASE={db};PORT={port};'
        f'charset={charset};'
    )
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
    print(f'{cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_NAME)}, version {cnxn.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_VER)}')
else:
    cnxn = MySQLdb.connect(
        host=host, user=user, passwd=passwd, db=db, port=port, charset=charset
    )

int_value = 123
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (id varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY, intcol int, othercol longblob)")
crsr.execute(f"INSERT INTO foo (id, intcol) VALUES ('Alfa', {int_value})")
sql = f"SELECT intcol, othercol FROM foo WHERE id = {'?' if use_odbc else '%s'}"
crsr.execute(sql, ('Alfa',))
result = crsr.fetchone()[0]
print(f'{"pass" if result == int_value else "FAIL"} -- expected: {repr(int_value)} ; actual: {repr(result)}')
```

Console output with `use_odbc = True`:

```
using ODBC ...
myodbc8a.dll, version 08.00.0018
FAIL -- expected: 123 ; actual: 0
```

Console output with `use_odbc = False`:

```
not using ODBC ...
pass -- expected: 123 ; actual: 123
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it and get following error: >>> cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM patients where patient_id=?", ('7',))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 210, in execute
    query = query % args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting @Gord Thompson

Comment: It looks like MySQLdb uses %s instead of ? in parameterized query. can you confirm @Gord Thompson

Comment: @Simrankaur re: parameter placeholders - Yes, you are correct.

Comment: So there is no way to use MySQLdb without having to change parameter placeholders? I would have liked to avoid making this change in all my queries @Gord Thompson

Comment: A possible workaround, as suggested by the other answer, may be to use an older version of MySQL Connector/ODBC.

Comment: Ah okay. I was under the impression that other versions of ODBC connector will not work with MySQL 8. Do we know which of them are going to work fine with MySQL 8? @Gord Thompson

Comment: With ODBC 5.3, I get : pyodbc.Error: ('07006', u'[07006] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-8.0.18]Source character set not supported by client (0) (SQLGetData)')

Comment: I created your "patient" table in MySQL and tried to reproduce your issue but I couldn't, either with MySQL Connector/ODBC 8.00.18 (via pyodbc) or with mysqlclient. In any case, another possible workaround for ODBC 8.x would be to first SELECT only the `int` columns, then do a second SELECT to retrieve the remaining columns for the same row(s). Or, you could fall back to dynamic SQL, which for a query like `SELECT * ... WHERE patient_id = 7` would not pose a significant risk of SQL injection issues.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW i just posted a question where i was seeing this in version 3.1.14 of the ODBC connector but NOT in version 3.1.10.

Comment: Ah, I  am using ODBC connector 8 for MySQL 8