# MySql ODBC connector 3.1.14 and mariaDB ; int columns zero

Tags: mysql, odbc, mariadb, visual-foxpro

tried to update to this version of the odbc connector from 3.1.10 but a simple select * always returns zeros in all int columns, decimal columns are ok.

The 3.1.10 version of the connector returns correct values in the same int columns.

This is 32bit driver from vfp9 accessing a MariaDB server version 10.3.11.

is there a new setting i'm missing?

thanks

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58674295/2144390

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58674295/2144390

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97191