# MS Access + ODBC 8.0 + MySQL some field show first 10 rows =0, though MySQL shows other values

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

FEATURES:
MS ACCESS 2010 + ODBC conector + MySQL server

PROBLEM:
All fields with datatype INT in first 10 rows show 0 (zero) values. If I short asc or desc still first 10 rows with INT = 0. When I trying to edit that records, sometimes I get "The data has been changed", but sometimes when update some field in these records, real value appears. Until I close and open that table, than value again become 0

I workaround all day to find solution, but I cant handle this problem.
I have more than 10 tables, but problem only in this main orders table, which has size 4.0 MB and about 8000 rows. There is 76 columns, whit INT, BIT, FLOAT, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP, CHAR, VARCHAR datatypes and 2 fields with expression (VIRTUAL).

I tried to reduce columns and records count, but it didn't help.

Comment: Make sure that MS SQL client installed is suitable for database. Such kind glitches may appear if you use incorrect version

Comment: Please post your MySQL server version. ODBC connector version. If you are using `bit` data type, make sure it has a default value of either `1 or 0` in MySql.

Comment: ODBC - 8.0.18. MySQL - 5.7.26. All bit field has default value = 0

Comment: use mysql odbc driver 5.9.9 - 12

Comment: @krishKM did mean MySQL server version? Is there no other way so solve this problem?

Comment: no your odbc connector. uninstall and install version from 5.9.9 - 12

Comment: @krishKM: you talk about 5.3.9 - 12? There is no Connector/ODBC 5.9.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [MySQL Connector/ODBC Bug #91191](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97191).

> When running a SELECT prepared statement using Classic ASP/VBScript and ODBC (I tested both version 8.0.17 & 5.3.13, 32-bit/64-bit) any column that is an INT datatype always returns a value of 0.

Just fixed with [MySQL Connector/ODBC 8.0.19](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-odbc/en/news-8-0-19.html)